# Java comparator issue when passed to Collections.sort

Tags: java, collections, comparator

When testing with less load in local it worked fine.

```
private static class CoordinateComparator implements Comparator<Coordinate> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Coordinate o1, Coordinate o2) {
        return o1.x <= o2.x ? -1 : 1;
    }

}
```

Here x is primitive and it was giving runtime error when tests were run. Under heavy load it was breaking.

Then i changed comparator to:-

```
private static class CoordinateComparator implements Comparator<Coordinate> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Coordinate o1, Coordinate o2) {
        return o1.x.compareTo(o2.x);
    }

}
```

In this case x is Integer. Then it started working fine.
Any ideas or thoughts why this was happening. I was passing this comparator to Collections.sort(array, comp)

Comment: what runtime error are you getting for the first case ??

Comment: It was during a competitive coding. They just gave RE not exact error.

Comment: I tested the same problem after accounting for o1.x == o2.x return 0. And it worked fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)` would throw 
`IllegalArgumentException` if the comparator is found to violate the `Comparator` contract.

In your code, the first `compare` method is inconsistent for the case where `o1.x` is equal to `o2.x`. It will return either -1 or 1 depending on the order in which the instances are compared. It should return 0 in this case.

You can fix it as follows:

```
public int compare(Coordinate o1, Coordinate o2) {
    return o1.x < o2.x ? -1 : o1.x > o2.x ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Though your `o1.x.compareTo(o2.x)` alternative seems cleaner to me.

Comment: Why not simply write `o1.x - o2.x`?

Comment: @AshutoshJha it might, since your Comparator is violating the contract.

Comment: @Lino if there's no danger of numeric overflow, you can certainly write that (I'm not sure what's the type of `x` and what range of values it may contain).

Comment: @Eran The OP wrote *In this case x is Integer* so it should be fine

Comment: @Lino depends on how large and how small these integers can be. For example, if you subtract Integer.MAX_VALUE from any negative value, you'll get numeric overflow.

Comment: @Eran thanks. I got your point, we need to cover all cases. I thought if o1.x<=o2.x return -1 as it didn't matter to me then. But it violated the contract. Thanks

Comment: @AshutoshJha how can you say "it didn't matter to me", when you are going to pass this comparator to a sort or search routine, you didn't write, so you don't know what matters to these routines?

Comment: @Holger Sorry i will take care of these things in future